# Problems with insertion of data in F-02 batch input ABAP

Tags: ui-automation, abap, sap-erp

I have the next Batch Input (BI) that register payments (`F-02`).

1. In the first position header data bank and the amount are recorded.
2. The first condition of a customer payment is recorded.
3. In the last condition other payment of a customer is recorded.

In the latter condition it does not run anything, someone could help me please?

Point 1 and 2 perform the same functionality with different values ​​only

```
PERFORM OPEN_GROUP.
    PERFORM BDC_DYNPRO USING 'SAPMF05A' '0100'.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BLDAT'   p_bldat.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BUDAT'   p_budat.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-XBLNR'   p_xblnr.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BKTXT'   p_bktxt.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BLART'   p_blart.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-MONAT'   p_monat.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-BUKRS'   p_bukrs.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BKPF-WAERS'   p_waers.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'RF05A-NEWBS'  '40'.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'RF05A-NEWKO'  p_newko.
    PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BDC_OKCODE' '/00'.
    PERFORM BDC_DYNPRO USING 'SAPMF05A' '0300'.
      WRITE p_wrbtr TO v_importe.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BSEG-WRBTR'   v_importe.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BSEG-SGTXT'   p_sgtxt.


    IF NOT p_cwrbtr IS INITIAL.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'RF05A-NEWBS'  '15'.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'RF05A-NEWKO'  p_cnewko.
    PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BDC_OKCODE' '/00'.

    PERFORM BDC_DYNPRO USING 'SAPLKACB' '0002'.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'COBL-GSBER'   p_gsber.
    PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BDC_OKCODE' '=ENTE'.

    PERFORM BDC_DYNPRO USING 'SAPMF05A' '0301'.
      WRITE p_cwrbtr TO v_cimporte.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BSEG-WRBTR'   v_cimporte.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BSEG-GSBER'   p_gsber.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BSEG-ZFBDT'   p_budat.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BSEG-SGTXT'   p_csgtxt.
    PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BDC_OKCODE' '/00'.

    ENDIF.

    IF NOT p_owrbtr IS INITIAL.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'RF05A-NEWBS'  '15'.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'RF05A-NEWKO'  '511'.
    PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BDC_OKCODE' '/00'.

    PERFORM BDC_DYNPRO USING 'SAPLKACB' '0002'.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'COBL-GSBER'   p_gsber.
    PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BDC_OKCODE' '=ENTE'.

    PERFORM BDC_DYNPRO USING 'SAPMF05A' '0301'.
      WRITE p_owrbtr TO v_oimporte.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BSEG-WRBTR'   v_oimporte.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BSEG-GSBER'   p_gsber.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BSEG-ZFBDT'   p_budat.
      PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BSEG-SGTXT'   p_osgtxt.
    PERFORM BDC_FIELD  USING 'BDC_OKCODE' '=BU'.

    ENDIF.
    PERFORM BDC_TRANSACTION USING 'F-02'.
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you get? What is the error message?

Comment: @Jagger 
 
Sorry but. The second IF does its function. Error No batch input data for screen SAPMF05A 0301

Comment: Do you run your batch input session in dialog or in background?